# Calculating differences in time from multiple rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, datediff

```
EquipmentUseId  CollectionPointId  EmployeeNum  ShopOrder  StartDateTime
366                 69             9999         999999     4/26/13 3:29 PM
373                 69             4878         107321     4/26/13 10:19 PM
385                 69             4971         107321     4/27/13 7:35 AM
393                 69             4179         107325     4/30/13 7:24 AM
394                 69             4179         107325     4/30/13 7:38 AM
395                 69             4179         107325     4/30/13 10:28 AM
398                 69             4179         107325     4/30/13 2:41 PM
399                 69             9999         999999     4/30/13 2:43 PM
400                 69             9999         999999     4/30/13 2:46 PM
```

Given the above table, I'm left with a unique problem and describing it may be just as difficult.  There is a StartDateTime for each ShopOrder per Employee but no StopDateTime, this is by design.  However I need to be able to calculate the difference in time between the StartDateTime of one ShopOrder and the StartDateTime of the next ShopOrder.  An example: SO # 999999 starts at 15:29 on 4/26 by Employee 9999, then a new SO # of 107321 is started at 22:19 on 4/26 by Employee 4878.  I would need to calculate the difference between 4/26/2013 22:19 and 4/26/2013 15:29.  This would give me the clock out date for SO# 9999 but it's actually need for a secondary process.  For now I just need to be able get the time.  One hang-up is if the SO #'s are the same then I would only use the first StartDateTime, and the first StartDateTime of the next SO #.  Sorry this is so long, I'm not even sure if I've explained anything at this point.

Please go easy on me...it's been a long day.

> **Edited for output on 08/19/2013:**
>
> After mulling it over during the weekend, I decided it would be best
>   to use an EndDateTime as this query is only the first step in the
>   overall application/report.
>
> Also, the EmployeeNum is not relevant anymore to this portion of the application.
>
> This is how it should look (The EquipmentUseID is PK, the
>   CollectionPointID is always 69 so they don't need to be shown on the
>   output)?
>
> ```
> ShopOrder    StartDateTime        EndDateTime
> 999999       4/26/13 3:29 PM      4/26/13 10:19 PM
> 107321       4/26/13 10:19 PM     4/30/13 7:24 AM
> 107325       4/30/13 7:24 AM      4/30/13 2:43 PM
> 999999       4/30/13 2:43 PM      <next SO# StartDateTime>
> ```
>
> To sum up this table, I need the **SO#**, the **StartDateTime per SO#** (already in the table),
>   and the **EndDateTime** which is the actually the StartDateTime for the next SO#.  Hopefully this clears 
>   it up, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: use an inline view where you first get the max date per shop order, then look up LAG functions and loop over those doing the time diff

Comment: @randy No lag in SQL 2005

Comment: @ctmcklowe96 could you provide desired output for given input?

Comment: @RomanPekar - The output and a bit more explanation begin with the "Edited for output..." in bold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with orderedTickets as 
(
    select ShopOrder, min(StartDateTime) as date 
         , row_number() over (order by min(StartDateTime)) as rownumber
    from table 
    where ShopOrder is not null  
    group by ShopOrder
)
select t1.ShopOrder, datediff(ss, t1.StartDateTime, t2.StartDateTime) 
  from orderedTickets as t1 
  join orderedTickets as t2 
    on t2.rownumber = t1.rownumber + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to the first problem, which is getting the next date time on the "next" shop order.  This solution uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*, nextStartDateTime - StartDateTime -- or use datediff() here if you want the time in particular units
from (select t.*,
             (select top 1 StartDateTime
              from t t2
              where t2.StartDateTime > t.StartDateTime and
                    t2.ShopOrder <> t.ShopOrder
              order by StartDateTime
             ) as nextStartDateTime
      from t
     ) t;
```

The second problem is getting the first record for a given shop order.  I'm not sure I understand this fully.  It would help if you edited the question to explain the results that you want on the data provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use CTE, -

```
;with Equipment as 
(
select EquipmentUseId, CollectionPointId, EmployeeNum, ShopOrder, StartDateTime, row_number() over (PARTITION BY ShopOrder order by EquipmentUseId) as rownumber
from your_table 
),
Equipment2 AS (
select EquipmentUseId, CollectionPointId, EmployeeNum, ShopOrder, StartDateTime, row_number() over (order by EquipmentUseId) as rownumber
from Equipment WHERE rownumber = 1
)

SELECT t1.EquipmentUseId,
   t1.CollectionPointId,
   t1.EmployeeNum,
   t1.ShopOrder,
   t1.StartDateTime,
   CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(n, t1.StartDateTime, t2.StartDateTime) / 60) + ':' +  RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,(DATEDIFF(n, t1.StartDateTime, t2.StartDateTime)%60)), 2) time_diff
FROM   Equipment2 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Equipment2 AS t2 ON  t2.rownumber = t1.rownumber + 1
```